# UIButton click, Alamofire POST call, doesnt performSegue with a successful Firebase Login

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have a simple button action

I do verify the email and password before going into this, but this is my Firebase code. When you click on the button, it will get into the `VerifyUserInformation` function and the response will spit out. Basically, the segue's in `VerifyUserInformation` will not run for me, the dismiss function doesn't dismiss the modal (present full screen) either.

What can be done to fix this?

```
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailOutlet.text!, password: passwordOutlet.text!) { [weak self] user, error in
            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
            
                if let error = error {
                    self!.displaySnackbar(messageString: "\(error.localizedDescription)")
                    return
                }
            
            self!.preferences.setValue(true, forKey:SHARED_PREF_USER_LOGGED_IN_KEY)

            
            var firstTimeUser = self!.preferences.bool(forKey:FIRST_TIME_USER)
            
            print("\(self!.TAG) FirstTimeUser: \(firstTimeUser)")

            if (firstTimeUser) {
                print("\(self!.TAG) This is the first time the user is using the application.")
                self?.VerifyUserInformation(firebaseId: "\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)")
            } else {
                print("\(self!.TAG) User can head into the Application.")
                self!.performSegue(withIdentifier: "MainScreen", sender: nil)
                self?.progressBar.isHidden = true
                self!.loginButtonOutlet.isHidden = false
            }
            
            
            
        }
```

To verify the user, I run this function.

```
func VerifyUserInformation(firebaseId: String) {
    
    let urlString = ADD_USER_FOR_ACCOUNT
    
    let param = [
       FROM_APP: "true",
       USER_FIREBASE_ID: firebaseId,
       GET_USER_ACCOUNT_INFORMATION: "true"
        ] as [String : Any]
    
    
    AF.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: param ,encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseJSON {
    response in
      switch response.result {
        case .success:
            print("\(self.TAG)\n***Response***\n\(response)\n***END***")
            if let result = response.value {
                let JSON = result as! NSDictionary

                let errorResponse = JSON["error"] as! Int
                if (errorResponse == 1) {
                    print("\(self.TAG) Error verifying the user.")
                    self.displaySnackbar(messageString: "Error verifying user. Try again.")
                } else {
                    print("\(self.TAG) User is verified")
                    let messageResponse = JSON["message"] as! String
                    if (messageResponse == "user has items") {
                        print("\(self.TAG) User has items, go into MainScreen")
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
                                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "MainScreen", sender: nil)
                                self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
                                self.preferences.setValue(false, forKey:FIRST_TIME_USER)
                                self.loginButtonOutlet.isHidden = false
                                self.progressBar.isHidden = true
                            }
                        }
                        
                    } else {
                        print("\(self.TAG) User has 0 items, go into Second Onboarding")
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
                                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SecondOnBoarding", sender: nil)
                                self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
                                self.loginButtonOutlet.isHidden = false
                                self.progressBar.isHidden = true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            break
        case .failure(let error):
            self.loginButtonOutlet.isHidden = false
            self.progressBar.isHidden = true
            self.displaySnackbar(messageString: "Error getting user information. Try again.")
            print("\(self.TAG) \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: Can you post the result of `printDebug(result)` of your `AF` request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing the `dismiss()`, it started to work.